# Configuring IntelliJ Platform plugin's workspace

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I've been setting up the workspace for IntelliJ's plugin development. There is one issue that I'm not able to solve.

I have two plugins: A and B. The B plugin depends on A. The A plugin is provided as an install-ready zip package (I don't have the code and I don't want to add it to my project).

In the manual, I met [this page](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_dependencies.html). I added jars from the A plugin (extracted from the zip file) to the SDK that is use when running B plugin. Unfortunately, when the sandbox is being bootstrapped, I get the following error:

```
Problems found loading plugins:
Plugin "B" was not loaded: required plugin "A" not installed.

Disable B
Open plugin manager
```

Does it mean that plugins from the SDK are not installed automatically?

I tried to install the A plugin in the sandbox but then I got a casting exception - two different class loaders were used.

Of course, I have appropriate dependency configuration in the B.plugin.xml file:

```
<depends>A</depends>
```

My question is how should I provide the A plugin to be able to develop the B plugin? Is it possible to develop the B plugin without A's sources?

In the jars that I added to the SDK's classpath, there is a package that contains the plugin.xml file for the A plugin. This plugin is also not listed on the list of plugins.

I'm sure that both plugins are configured properly because there are no problems when I install both of them in a standalone IntelliJ instance. Additionally, I don't have any compilation errors.

After couple more hours of debugging. The A plugin is marked as not installed because in the PluginManagerCore:loadDescriptorsFromClassPath method there are no appropriate jars URLs provided. It seems that BootstrapClassLoaderUtil doesn't include all of the entries configured in the SDK.

I tried to set *-Didea.additional.classpath* property, but I got the class cast exception again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the solution.

The B plugin consists of other B submodules:

- B.submodule-1
- B.submodule-2
- B.submodule-3

One of these submodules had dependencies to the A's submodule. Something like this:

```
B:
| B.plugin-submodule
| B.submodule-1
   | A.submodule1
   | A.submodule2
| B.submodule-2
| B.submodule-3
```

Based on the gradle setup, IntelliJ resolved all of the dependencies for all submodules. Initially, I removed Gradle dependencies and set the JDK only for the plugin submodule. It was required to do so for the others (submodule-1/2/3).